# Reference data of Class B from another Class A in C#

Tags: c#

I know how to reference a method of class B from class A, but I am struggling with referring the data. For instance

```
class A 
{
    int[] array1;
    method 1
    {
        //do something and ...
        array1 = something;
    }
}
```

Then in class B

```
class B
{
    int[] array2 = new B.array;
}
```

But array2 here is just new blank data structure with no actual data in it. In Class B, how could I use the existing array1 data of class A?

For example, array1 may be video streaming data.

Thank you,
Sean

Comment: More information is needed.  Is there a relationship between class A and class B?  Is class B a subclass of class A?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. I'd comment on your post, but I don't have enough rep points (50). You could create a public method on Class A to expose array1 data - that's pretty basic stuff. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: It would help if your example wasn't a mix of valid and invalid C# syntax.

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, but it sounds like you need to spend some more time with basic introductory materials to C#. This site is for programming problems, your question reads more like "I'm using the language for the first time." Please spend more time with freely available tutorials or other reference materials.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I intended to put pseudo code rather than actual code here for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of points of confusion.

First, in `Class A`, the member variable `Array 1` defaults to private access, so you cannot "see" it from Class B.

Secondly, good design would require you to present `Array 1` as a *property* of `Class A` as follows:

```
class A
{
int[] array1;

public int[] TheArray
  {
    get { return array1; }
    set { array1 = value; }
  }
}
```

Then you could write:

```
class B

void myMethod() {
 int[] array2 = A.TheArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the array public in class `A`. You can then access it from an existing instance of `A`, in `B`.

```
class B
{
    int[] array2;

    // constructor function for class B
    public B(A aInstance) {
        // set array2 to aInstance's array1
        array2 = aInstance.array1;
    }
}

A a = new A();
B b = new B(a);
```

You can also make `array1` static in `A`. From there you can access it from just `A.array1`.

**[Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**